# Stripe create a new customer each payement

Tags: stripe-payments

**SOLUTION :**  Store in db the object Charge with the user id and check each time if we know this user or not :

```
 $customerAlreadyKnown = OrdersModel::checkIfUserKnown($email);
```

If we know it then we have to update customer source (don't know why) :

```
if(gettype($customerAlreadyKnown)=='array'){
            \Stripe\Customer::update(
                $customerAlreadyKnown[0]['user_id'],
                ['source' => $token]
            );
            $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
                'customer' => $customerAlreadyKnown[0]['user_id'],
                'amount' => $itemPrice,
                'currency' => 'eur',
                'description' => $_POST['description'],
                'metadata' => array(
                    'order_id' => $orderID,
                ),
            ]);
```

Else we create a new customer

```
        }else{
            // Add customer to stripe
            $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
                'email' => $email,
                'card' => $token,
            ));

            $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
                'customer' => $customer->id,
                'amount' => $itemPrice,
                'currency' => 'eur',
                'description' => $_POST['description'],
                'metadata' => array(
                    'order_id' => $orderID,
                ),
            ]);
        }
```

Comment: Well, what did you think `Customer::create` would do? You need to search for an existing customer before you go creating one, and use it in the `Charge::create` call instead.

Comment: Yes, but I don't find how to do it in there doc... they have a \Stripe\Customer::retrieve('cus_GvtXe1bYKwCBk2'); but I don't know how to get the id

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/list; pay special attention to the `email` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new `Token` and `Customer` for each payment. You should instead identify your existing Customers (store a relation table locally on your application) in some way (e.g. by their [email_address](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/object#customer_object-email) or the `Token`'s [Card fingerprint](https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens/object#token_object-card-fingerprint)). Then instead of using the new `Token` and a new `Customer`, retrieve the existing customer as `$customer` before you charge (their existing Card will be used automatically).

Comment: Ahhh I don't think about store the customer id, it's in the charge object so I could store it and then use the \Stripe\Customer::retrieve('cus_GvtXe1bYKwCBk2')

Comment: Ok but now I have an error "Customer cus_GvvCtjg4I1Vdic does not have a linked source with ID tok_1GO3S8F0S5meJa3hmxe8njSw"